# Classical results of Algebraic Geometry using cohomology.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, big-list

I am looking for  classical results of Algebraic Geometry that can be proved using cohomology. For example, Riemann-Roch Theorem and Bezout Theorem admits short proofs (providing that you know enough about cohomology) using this kind of techniques. Are there any others? Which is your favourite one?

What about Pappus Theorem or any other projective geometry theorem?

Comment: Pappus theorem is a corollary of Bezout's theorem which is a corollary of sheaf theory. So in some sense you can proof Pappus theorem using sheaf theory.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Weil conjectires are one of the best examples given the key role they played as motivation for introducing many cohomology theories, most famously étale cohomology.